# What is the Azure Guest operating system?

Tags: azure

According to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix.md) Azure supports only `Windows Server 2012 R2` `Windows Server 2012`
`Windows Server 2008R2`.

That's mean that I cannot deploy anything else?

Comment: This is only for cloud services. Cloud services are a special case (stateless machines) What do you want to deploy? Azure also supports VM's with more options including Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding a bit on @Erik's comment:

The article you linked to is all about Cloud Services. Azure Cloud Services (web and worker role instances) are stateless Windows Server VMs that you don't have to manage (you just deploy a package built by specific developer tools such as Visual Studio). Very easy to scale out (or in), and no worries about maintaining the OS.

Azure's Virtual Machines, on the other hand, support many different flavors of both Windows Server (2012, 2016 preview, etc) and Linux (Ubuntu, Red Hat, CentOS, etc). You have to manage the OS maintenance, and you have some more work to do around scaling (and there are different features around this, such as VM scale sets).

Answer (score 1):

Those are the limitations for Cloud Services. Web Apps would be similar to that too since you can't explicitly choose which server operating system to host those.

With Azure VM's (Virtual Machines) you have a much wider array of options to choose from. There are a number of Operating Systems, different Windows versions as well as Linux, to choose from in the Azure Marketplace. You can also build a VM locally using Hyper-V and then upload the .VHD into Azure to run it there as a VM.